# Dart : Benefits of overriding the compareTo method on an enhanced enum

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types

```
enum Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle> {
  car(tires: 4, passengers: 5, carbonPerKilometer: 400),
  bus(tires: 6, passengers: 50, carbonPerKilometer: 800),
  bicycle(tires: 2, passengers: 1, carbonPerKilometer: 0);

  const Vehicle({
    required this.tires,
    required this.passengers,
    required this.carbonPerKilometer,
  });

  final int tires;
  final int passengers;
  final int carbonPerKilometer;

  int get carbonFootprint => (carbonPerKilometer / passengers).round();

  @override
  int compareTo(Vehicle other) => carbonFootprint - other.carbonFootprint;
}
```

This is the explanation of "enhanced enum" that can be used with Dart 2.17 or later.

It seems that enums can now implement abstract classes (the sample overrides (implements) the compareTo method of the Compareable class).
What are the specific benefits of implementing the compareTo method in the sample above?

I can't think of anything like "The compareTo method makes it possible to write code like this, which is very convenient."

The code that comes to mind is like the one below, but are there any other benefits?

```
void main(){
  test('Vehicle test',(){
    expect(Vehicle.car.compareTo(Vehicle.bus) > 0, isTrue);
    expect(Vehicle.bus.compareTo(Vehicle.bicycle) > 0, isTrue);
    expect(Vehicle.bicycle.compareTo(Vehicle.car) < 0, isTrue);
  });
}
```

Comment: Implementing `Comparable` means that things such as `List.sort` will automatically work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I can sort List of enums automatically.